# Geo region codes list

Tags: php, csv, geo

I need geo database in format County->Region->City. I use this database:

https://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

As i understand country code use ISO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2. For example this line:

```
us,sand point,Sand Point,AK,,55.3397222,-160.4972222
```

mean:

```
US         - County United States
Sand Point - City name
AK         - Region Alaska
```

But where i can get list of regions codes?

Thank you.

Comment: I googled "maxmind region codes" and found: http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The region codes are listed here:

http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv

The first column is the country code, the second column is the region code within that country. So this line means that `AK` in `US` is Alaska:

```
US,AK,"Alaska"
```

Comment: I know it is an old post.. but in the cities file all region codes are in numbers and in this file for canada and USA its letters. Do you know that is the correspondences between the two?

Comment: Which city file are you talking about?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Are you talking about `GeoLiteCity-Blocks.csv`? The codes there refer to the `locId` column in `GeoLiteCity-Location.csv`.

Comment: And in that file, the `country` and `region` columns correspond to those columns in `region_codes.csv`.

Comment: the free download file in this link https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi The region codes in that file look the same as the region codes in `region_codes.csv`. For instance, Sacramento, California has region code `CA`.

Comment: you are right but for canada it does not add up. example: ca,montreal,Montreal,10,3268513,45.5,-73.583333 and region should be QC.

Comment: I don't know. They're both legacy databases, I guess they're not intended to be used together.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi My guess is that at some time they changed how they were doing Candian regions. But they didn't want to make an incompatible change to the older file formats.